# Prevent PJLIB from printing initial information

Tags: c++, initialization

I am using [PJLIB 2.0.1](http://www.pjsip.org/pjlib/docs/html/), especially the memory pool, since it is said to be "very very fast".

However, after the program starts, it automatically outputs "14:26:12.944 os_core_unix.c !pjlib 2.0.1 for POSIX initialized", which is annoying.

I am not familiar with PJLIB... Can anyone advise how I can turn off such output? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the logging level by using `void pj_log_set_level(int level)`. If you want to turn it completely off, call `pj_log_set_level(0);` at the beginning of your code. Also, at compile time, you can define the logging level likes this:

```
#undef PJ_LOG_MAX_LEVEL
#define PJ_LOG_MAX_LEVEL 0
```

There are 6 levels you can set to, `6` being the most verbose and `0`  turning it off. For more info, [see here](http://www.pjsip.org/pjlib/docs/html/group__PJ__LOG.htm). However, logging is nice for debugging code, so you might not want to turn it off.

Comment: That great, thanks. Can I also ask in function pj_pool_alloc(pj_pool_t * pool, pj_size_t size ), does "size" mean in byte or other units? Thanks.

Comment: It works fine with pj_log_set_level(0). However, if I use the macro, it complains "warning: "PJ_LOG_MAX_LEVEL" redefined".

Comment: @jason.Z: Yeah, you have to `#undef` before you define it again (added the example to my answer). However, it would be better to use `pj_log_set_level(0);`. Also, "size" means the chunk of memory in bytes.

Comment: I guess the macro does NOT work, even if undef first. It still gives that output...

Comment: Did you put it *after* all the headers you included?